# How to check if the input string is character, number or not in assembly x86 using MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So this is my code and I can't seem to think where am I getting it wrong. I am trying to do an exercise that will accept 5 digit numbers as an input and tells you if the number is an odd or even.  The program should be able to handle errors if the number is more than 5 digits, and there is non-numeric characters as an input. I am still a beginner in assembly language and searching almost everywhere in Google for answer to every step and functions

```
getNumber:
         push offset msg        ; put in to stack the effective addr of msg
       call StdOut                  ; call console display API

       push 100                    ; set the maximum input character
       push offset buffer       ; put in to stack the effective addr of input storage
       call StdIn                    ; call console input API

       push offset input       ; put in to stack the effective addr of msg2
       call StdOut                 ; call console display API

       push offset buffer      ; put in to stack the effective addr of input storage
       call compare
compare:
            lea edx, [buffer]
            mov al, byte ptr [edx]
            cmp al,'/'  
            jle notNumber
            cmp al, 'a'
            jb notNumber
            cmp al, 'z'
            ja notNumber
            cmp al,':'  
            jge notNumber
            cmp al,30h
            jge aNumber
            ret

aNumber:
            push offset aNum
            call StdOut
            call exit
notNumber:
            push offset notNum
            call StdOut
            call exit
end getNumber
```

Comment: if you want to check the number entered, "take as an input" is more than just reading the ascii string from stdIn. You should write a function to convert the string to an integer. This function could also report the error, if there are non-digit numbers. your "compare" part only checks a single (the first) digit entered

Comment: Mmm... I believe your question is off-topic because it is both too broad and a request to debug your code. However, if you need some input and willing to learn you can [ping me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5801661/margaret-bloom) :) but be warned that I don't like lazy or cheating students.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just an excerpt of your code.  Even so, take note that, as written here, `getNumber` will "fall through" into `compare`.  If you follow it through, you display a message, get input, display the input, call compare....  when compare returns, it "falls through" into compare again.  When you hit that return a second time, you will have serious issues since whatever's on the stack will be assumed to be a return address.

Comment: @MargaretBloom requests to assist debugging code aren't off-topic as long as they are MVC with defined behaviors and an explanation of what has already been tried.

Comment: My bad @DavidHoelzer, I used the wrong words. However, I still believe this question is too localised for SO.

Comment: Note that you can check if a number is odd or even by looking only at the last base10 digit, because 10 is a multiple of 2.  (In fact, you can just check the low bit of the ASCII digit with `test al, 1`).  So you can skip actually converting the number to an integer.  Or does this have to work for other number bases?  I see you're checking for something to do with `'a'` and `'z'`, instead of just `'0'` to `'9'`.  From the text, it sound like you only need to detect digit vs. non-digit, not whether the byte might be alphabetic or anything else.